# Does a security breach on a site with Google login mean my Google account is compromised?

Tags: passwords, google

[Firefox Monitor](https://monitor.firefox.com) has given me a warning that [Lumin PDF](https://www.luminpdf.com/) has been hacked.

[image: Lumin PDF warning]

However, I use my Google account to login to Lumin, which I believe means Lumin did not store a password for me.

**Does the Lumin PDF hack mean that my Google account may be compromised in any way?**

The warnings for Firefox Monitor don't seem to ever go away, even after changing relevant passwords, so I am unclear on the status of my accounts with sites they warn me about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "Login with Google/Facebook/etc." option, then, no, that site does not get your password.

You actually log into Google/Facebook/etc. and then they tell the site that you successfully logged in.

If you want to know more, the technology that is used to do this is called "[Single Sign On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)". All the guides online get very technical, but the idea is that the site trusts Google/Facebook/etc. to tell them that you are you (authentication).